# Tipos de datos en json

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente query en Larevel

```
$HorasHombrexReparacion = DB::SELECT('SELECT top 1 MAX(HorasHombrexReparacion)  AS HorasHombrexReparacion FROM tGestionMant GROUP BY AreaSolicitante');

return response()->json([ 'data' => [$HorasHombrexReparacion]]);
```

En el en la base de datos el campo es de tipo float, y el json me lo devuelve como string:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "HorasHombrexReparacion": "2872"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Porque sucede esto ?

Comment: Porque todo es un string para json.. no hay un tipo de dato asociado. Vos sos quien debe ocuparse del tipo de datos.

Comment: que tal si intentan con esto return response()->json([ 'data' => [(float)$HorasHombrexReparacion]]);

Comment: Me devuelve esto:

{
  "data": [
    1
  ]
}

Cuando me tendría que devolver :
{
  "data": [
    2872
  ]
}

Comment: hice la prueba en tinker y esto es lo que obtuve `>>> $numero = "2872";
=> "2872"
>>> return response()->json(['data' => [(float)$numero]]);
=> Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse {#4078
     +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#4081},
     +original: [
       "data" => [
         2872.0,
       ],
     ],
     +exception: null,
   }
>>> 
`

Comment: En el ejemplo si devuelve el numero como float, pero como se integraría en el resutado :

{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "HorasHombrexReparacion": "2872"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Quiero que muestre asi;
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "HorasHombrexReparacion": 2872
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: De que manera se define los tipos de datos ?

Comment: Los define quien lee el dato.

Comment: intenta con esta estructura: `$HorasHombrexReparacion = "2872"; $response = [ 'data' => [ 'HorasHombrexReparacion' => (float) $HorasHombrexReparacion ] ]; return response()->json($response);`

Comment: Estuve investigando respecto, y encontré Attribute Casting in Laravel Eloquent Models aplicado en Laravel, https://www.larashout.com/attribute-casting-in-laravel-eloquent-models

Comment: Ya apliqué lo que indica pero aun me muestra el string,Documentación oficial :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 0):

[Solución]

```
  function data_cahrt(){

     $data = DB::SELECT('SELECT  MAX(AreaSolicitante) AS AreaSolicitante , ROUND( MAX(HorasHombrexReparacion), 2) AS HorasHombrexReparacion FROM tGestionMant GROUP BY AreaSolicitante');
     $array[] = ['AreaSolicitante', 'HorasHombrexReparacion'];
     foreach($data as $key => $value){
      $array[++$key] = [$value->AreaSolicitante, (float)$value->HorasHombrexReparacion];
     }
     return view('google_pie_chart')->with('AreaSolicitante', json_encode($array));
    }
```

Comment: Hola Carlos Vanegas, me alegro que encontraras una solución al problema y que la hayas compartido con la comunidad. Deberías añadir algo más de detalle con una pequeña descripción de qué hiciste para solucionar el problema y qué cambios hiciste en el código. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad ya que no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.